# Inconsistent results when counting day difference by yyyymmdd integer

Tags: java, date

I have struggled for this strange problem for a whole day. Here is the problem:

I have three line of code below

```
        float y=Float.parseFloat(line[1]);
        int dayDiff = DateUtil.countDay(lineDateid,testDateIdBelongTo,true);//
        dataBelongTo.set(dayDiff,y);// Some error thrown from here, so I set a break point here and watch
```

I found some strange IndexOutOfBound Exception in the third line, so I started to debug( with a breakpoint condition of `(dayDiff<0) || (dayDiff>=dataBelongTo.size())`) and notice the strange results, below is the screenshot:

[image]

I notice that the dayDiff is returning the unexpected results, and `DateUtil.countDay` seems return inconsistent result so I debug it in a main method :

```
    try {
        System.out.println("begins");
        for(int i=0; i< 500000;i++){//run 500000 times
           int dateDiff = DateUtil.countDay(20150604,20150601,true);
            if(dateDiff!=3) System.out.println(dateDiff);
        }
        System.out.println("ends");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But the results are right! Every time it returns 3(no error result prints)!!

Here is my code of `countDay`

```
public static int countDay(int day1, int day2 , boolean distinguish ) {
    int  res = 0;
    try {
        Date date1 = formatDate.parse(day1+"");
        Date date2 = formatDate.parse(day2 + "");
        long diff = date1.getTime() - date2.getTime();
        res = (int)TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(diff);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(!distinguish)
        res =Math.abs(res);

    return res;
}
```

And     `formatDate` is

```
public static final SimpleDateFormat formatDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
```

PS:  I am using JDK 7 and the problem code is running at Tomcat, and the data(param) is from MySQL .

Here is a more complete code of that problem part, there will be problem only for some cases.

```
    for(String[] line : tableData){//for each records in the database
        int lineDateid = Integer.parseInt(line[0]);//0 index is dateid
        int testDateIdBelongTo = 0;//init with 0
        JSONArray dataBelongTo = null;//data array 

        //below , need to assgin dataBelongTo and testDateIdBelongTo
        for(int i=0;i<testDates.length;i++){
            int testDate =testDates[i];
            NumberInterval interval = intervals.get(i);
            if(interval.isIn(lineDateid)){
                dataBelongTo = datas.get(i);
                testDateIdBelongTo=testDate;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(testDateIdBelongTo==0) throw new IllegalStateException("data errors, no matched dataid");


        float y=Float.parseFloat(line[1]);
        int dayDiff = DateUtil.countDay(lineDateid,testDateIdBelongTo,true);
        dataBelongTo.set(dayDiff,y);
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide [a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? What is `formatDate`?

Comment: Please provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. We've got snippets, the mention of MySQL etc - most of this is irrelevant. A simple console app could show us everything in a much clearer way.

Comment: @JonSkeet, as mentioned, I tried to reproduce it in main method but the method behaves well so I can't give a simple console app.

Comment: @Jaskey what is `formatDate`?

Comment: Using a floating point to hold a date is bad idea, could be the cause of the problem.

Comment: Side note: consider to use Java SE 8 and its new Date & Time API.

Comment: @assylias, updated the questions,     `public static final SimpleDateFormat formatDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");`

Comment: @Jaskey: That only shows that you need to do more diagnostic work to figure out the difference between your console app and running under Tomcat...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The likeliest reason is this:

```
public static final SimpleDateFormat formatDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
```

`SimpleDateFormat` is not thread safe and Tomcat probably calls this single instance from several threads.

Easy fix: remove the static variable and change your code:

```
public static int countDay(int day1, int day2 , boolean distinguish ) {
  SimpleDateFormat formatDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
  //rest of your code
}
```

If performance is a concern you could cache the formatters but that will make the code significantly more complicated (and as noted in the comments, the typical approach of using ThreadLocals is probably not recommended within an application server that manages its own thread pool).

You could also rewrite your code to not use SimpleDateFormat - that would probably be simpler.

As a side note, your current calculation is probably broken if the default time zone of the machine running the code has DST changes.

Comment: This will fix the immediate issues, but please be aware that (in general terms) a web container may create many threads, and so ThreadLocal may lead to leakage over time.

Comment: Thank you!!!!!You really save my day. The problem seems to be solved! I will accept your answer after I confirm it. If possible, would you please also post another solution with ThreadLocal at the answer. Thank you!